# pandas: calculate over multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

[image]

I would like to substract the values like:

[image]

minus

[image]

What I tried so far (the dataframe: http://pastebin.com/PydRHxcz):

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([key for key in dfdict], names = ['a','b','c','d'])
dfl = pd.DataFrame([dfdict[key] for key in dfdict],index=index)
dfl.columns = ['data']
dfl.sort(inplace=True)
d = dfl.unstack(['a','b'])
```

I can do:

```
d[0:5] - d[0:5]
```

And I get zeros for all values.

But If I do:

```
d[0:5] - d[5:]
```

I get Nans for all values. Any Ideas how I can perform such an operation ?

EDIT:

What works is

```
dfl.unstack(['a','b'])['data'][5:] - dfl.unstack(['a','b'])['data'][0:5].values
```

But it feels a bit clumsy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `loc` to select all rows that correspond to one label in the first level like this:

```
In [8]: d.loc[0]
Out[8]:
          data                                                        ...
a         0.17                                       1.00
b          0          5         10         500        0          5
d
0.0  11.098909   9.223784  8.003650  10.014445  13.231898  10.372040
0.3  14.349606  11.420565  9.053073  10.252542  26.342501  25.219403
0.5   1.336937   2.522929  3.875139  11.161803   3.168935   6.287555
0.7   0.379158   1.061104  2.053024  12.358577   0.678352   2.133887
1.0   0.210244   0.631631  1.457333  15.117805   0.292904   1.053916
```

So doing the subtraction looks like:

```
In [11]: d.loc[0] - d.loc[1000]
Out[11]:
           data                                                         ...
a          0.17                                        1.00
b           0          5          10        500         0          5
d
0.0   -3.870946  -3.239915  -3.504068 -0.722377   -2.335147  -2.460035
0.3  -65.611418 -42.225811 -25.712668 -1.028758  -65.106473 -44.067692
0.5  -84.494748 -55.186368 -34.184425 -1.619957  -89.356417 -69.008567
0.7  -92.681688 -61.636548 -37.386604 -4.227343 -110.501219 -78.925078
1.0 -101.071683 -61.758741 -37.080222 -3.081782 -103.779698 -80.337487
```

Comment: So easy. I just spend one hour playing around.